# ruby on rails routing error routing to the wrong page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

```
coordinates GET    /coordinates(.:format)          coordinates#index
                POST   /coordinates(.:format)          coordinates#create
 new_coordinate GET    /coordinates/new(.:format)      coordinates#new
edit_coordinate GET    /coordinates/:id/edit(.:format) coordinates#edit
     coordinate GET    /coordinates/:id(.:format)      coordinates#show
                PUT    /coordinates/:id(.:format)      coordinates#update
                DELETE /coordinates/:id(.:format)      coordinates#destroy
  tweets_search GET    /tweets/search(.:format)        tweets#search
   tweets_index GET    /tweets/index(.:format)         tweets#index

class TweetsController<ApplicationController

  def index
#include 'coordinates_controller.rb'
   include SearchHelper
include ParamasHelper
    @sql=a.search
    @tweets=Tweets.paginate_by_sql(sql, :@page, :per_page => @per_page ).all
  end
end
```

In my Rails app, I have two tables named `Coordinates` and `Tweets`. I have four actions to be rendered.

My `routes.rb` file

```
Tweetsblog2::Application.routes.draw do
resources :tweets, :coordinates
get "tweets/show"
get "tweets/index"
match "/tweets/show" => "tweets#show"
match "/tweets/index" => "tweets#index"
```

Whenever I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/tweets`, it's showing `tweets/index` instead of  `tweets/show` and the same error I am getting with different names.

When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/tweets/show`, it's giving `ArgumentError in TweetsController#show`.

When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/tweets/index` its giving `ArgumentError in TweetsController#show` same thing

My code for `show.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "tweets", action:"index" }, method: "get") do  %>
  <%= label_tag(:search, "search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:show) %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:search) %>
  <%= submit_tag("get results ") %>
<% end %>
```

My code for `index.html.erb`:

```
<%= will_paginate @tweets %>
<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>
<ul>
  <li><%= tweets.id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_created_at %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_source %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.tweet_text %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_id %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_sc_name %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_loc %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.user_img %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.longitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.latitude %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.place %></li>
  <li><%= tweets.country %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

It's not routing to the proper page. Please help me, I am stuck with this.

Comment: Can you post your `TweetController` as the likely hood of this error can be that you don't have this action set in your controller.

Comment: Sidenote - you should move your `<ul>` so it's on the outside of the `<% @tweets.each do |tweets| %>` block, like the `</ul>` is.

Comment: run `rake routes`  to show how the router sees your config file. .    the first `resources :tweets, :coordinates` is why it is matching /tweets to the #index action,  that is what the resources does.  also your match / get are kinda redundant.  since the match accepts any type (post/get) and the get only accepts get.

Comment: @David i have posted my TweetController

Answer (score 0):

-updating per comment-

```
Tweetsblog2::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :coordinates
    get "tweets/show"  => "tweets#show"
    get "tweets/index" => "tweets#index"
```

Removing the resources :tweets should fix your issue and allow you to use just call the 2 options.   The initial resources :tweets tells rails that you wanted resourceful routes (index shows all of the resource, show a specify one, etc..). So just building out the 2 non-resourceful routes as above sounds like what you want.   The way I normally do something like this is to just include the search form in in the index page and if there are no search params then show all tweets.)

Comment: @james thk u very much . @ doon  i dont want that way . its like a search button ,when i type something it should  display all the matching tweets, tweets# show is for the search button and tweets#index is for  displaying the matching queries. can u help pls?

Comment: i have  posted my rake routes can u help pls

Comment: small change i made search.html.erb is for the search page and index.html.erb is for displaying the results.

Comment: well search.html.erb will need either need to be called from the search action (just change show to search in the routes, etc..) else you will need to tell the show action to render the search.html.erb template with render :search  but in looking at your routes it *should* work.  Are you still getting the argument error on the show method?  and you are making sure to restart to server after making changes to your routes file?

Comment: yes i am  restarting every time but its not helping in anyway

Comment: also i declared a definition called search in my controller and also tried but  n ot working I am geting the same argument error

Comment: can you show the complete `TweetsController` source (or post a link to if if online?), also what are the SearchHelper and the paramashelper?   In #index where does `a` come from?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write

```
resources :tweets, except: [:index,:show]
```

because you declared you resource first, so rails is trying to match its default routing instead of your custom action:

```
get "tweets/index"
```

Comment: tries but that did'nt work , small change i should have mentioned .there is only one model  and coordinates and tweets are the two tables. can u help me pls to sort dis ?

Comment: i understand what you are trying to do, but i think you are not following Rails convention, thats why you are stuck.

Comment: can u pls temme  wat should i do ?